# Passing value from int as output parameter to a int Variable using LINQ in c#

Tags: c#, linq, output-parameter

I have a stored Procedure as

```
ALTER PROCEDURE  [dbo].[customers_iu] (@intId as int, @strName as nvarchar(100), @strSname as nvarchar(100),@intInsupdt as int = 0,   @intGnrtdid as int OUTPUT)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
if @intInsupdt = 1
begin
insert into dbo.customers (cust_Name, cust_Sname, cust_Tinno) values (@strName, @strSname,@strTinno) 
set @intGnrtdid = (select ident_Current('dbo.customers'))
end
else if @intInsupdt = 0
begin
update dbo.customers set cust_Name = @strName, cust_Tinno = @strTinno where cust_Id = @intId ;
set @intGnrtdid = @intId    
end
END
```

I want to get `@intGnrtdid`  value to a int Variable in using LINQ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See Scott Guthrie's excellent blog series on Linq to SQL. [Part 6](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/16/linq-to-sql-part-6-retrieving-data-using-stored-procedures.aspx) covers calling stored procedures. An out parameter would simply be represented by a `ref` parameter when calling your strongly typed stored procedure from code.